# Web API 2 Authentication

Tags: c#, jquery, asp.net, ajax, asp.net-web-api

I am trying to get authenticated my Mobile App ( for testing running from visual studio) to authenticate my Web API 2 Authentication Token in Single Page APP

**But Ajax always cancelled** with status cancelled

I have enabled CORS as below

```
var cors = new EnableCorsAttribute("*", "*", "*") {SupportsCredentials = true};
config.EnableCors(cors);

//Use only bearer token authentication
            config.SuppressDefaultHostAuthentication();
```

**Web Config**

```
 <system.web>
    <authentication mode="None" />
    <compilation debug="true" targetFramework="4.5" />
    <httpRuntime targetFramework="4.5" />
    <roleManager enabled="true" />
    <httpModules>
      <add name="ErrorLog" type="Elmah.ErrorLogModule, Elmah" />
      <add name="ErrorMail" type="Elmah.ErrorMailModule, Elmah" />
      <add name="ErrorFilter" type="Elmah.ErrorFilterModule, Elmah" />
    </httpModules>
  </system.web>
```

**My Ajax Request**

```
 $.ajax('http://retail.leap-tel.com/token', {
                type: "POST",
                data: data,
                xhrFields: {
                    withCredentials: true
                }
```

**Chorme Developer tools Log**

**Status : Cancelled**

```
Request URL:http://retail.leap-tel.com/token
Request Headersview source
Accept:*/*
Cache-Control:no-cache
Content-Type:application/x-www-form-urlencoded; charset=UTF-8
Origin:http://localhost:1539
Pragma:no-cache
Referer:http://localhost:1539/index.html
User-Agent:Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.3; WOW64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/31.0.1650.63 Safari/537.36
Form Dataview sourceview URL encoded
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I made some changes in DurandalAuth for enabling CORS and created a sample Javascript client in another repo

Check it out

https://github.com/yagopv/DurandalAuth/commit/4e7c09bc589345c946319b42d320e2b4d8313573

https://github.com/yagopv/DurandalAuthjsclient

Perhaps your main issue is about using the default Web API CORS attribute. You should use Microsoft.Owin.Cors attribute instead for working with the Owin middleware

Answer (score 0):

```
public static void Register(HttpConfiguration config)
{
    var corsAttribute = new EnableCorsAttribute("*", "*", "*");
    config.EnableCors(corsAttribute);

    // Web API configuration and services
    // Web API routes
    config.MapHttpAttributeRoutes();
}
```

Add `cors` attribute in `webapiConfig` class register method for application level.

Comment: Part of the code is out from the grey box. Please improve this for better readability